# Python BeautifulSoup find_all with regex doesn't match text

Tags: python, html, regex, beautifulsoup, python-re

I have the following HTML code:

```html
<a class="nav-link" href="https://cbd420.ch/fr/tous-les-produits/">
<span class="cbp-tab-title">
                                Shop <i class="fa fa-angle-down cbp-submenu-aindicator"></i></span>
</a>
```

I would like to get the anchor tag that has `Shop` as text disregarding the spacing before and after. I have tried the following code, but I keep getting an empty array:

```py
import re
html  = """<a class="nav-link" href="https://cbd420.ch/fr/tous-les-produits/">
<span class="cbp-tab-title">
                                Shop <i class="fa fa-angle-down cbp-submenu-aindicator"></i></span>
</a>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
prog = re.compile('\s*Shop\s*')
print(soup.find_all("a", string=prog))
# Output: []
```

I also tried retrieving the text using `get_text()`:

```py
text = soup.find_all("a")[0].get_text()
print(repr(text))
# Output: '\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tShop \n'
```

and ran the following code to make sure my Regex was right, which seems to be to the case.

```py
result = prog.match(text)
print(repr(result.group()))
# Output: '\n\n\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tShop \n'
```

I also tried selecting `span` instead of `a` but I get the same issue. I'm guessing it's something with `find_all`, I have read the [BeautifulSoup documentation](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) but I still can't find the issue. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Try `soup.find(lambda t: t.name == "a" and 'Shop' in t.text)`

Comment: Wow! Thanks. Any idea why it doesn't work with Regex? @WiktorStribiżew

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you have here is that the text you are looking for is in a tag that contains children tags, and when a tag has children tags, the `string` property is empty.

You can use a lambda expression in the `.find` call and since you are looking for a fixed string, you may use a mere `'Shop' in t.text` condition rather than a regex check:

```
soup.find(lambda t: t.name == "a" and 'Shop' in t.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

The text `Shop` you are searching it is inside `span` tag so when you are trying with regular expression its unable to fetch the value using regex.

You can try regex to find text and then parent of that.

```
import re
html  = """<a class="nav-link" href="https://cbd420.ch/fr/tous-les-produits/">
<span class="cbp-tab-title">
                                Shop <i class="fa fa-angle-down cbp-submenu-aindicator"></i></span>
</a>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.find(text=re.compile('Shop')).parent.parent)
```

If you have BS 4.7.1 or above you can use following css selector.

```
html  = """<a class="nav-link" href="https://cbd420.ch/fr/tous-les-produits/">
<span class="cbp-tab-title">
                                Shop <i class="fa fa-angle-down cbp-submenu-aindicator"></i></span>
</a>"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
print(soup.select_one('a:contains("Shop")'))
```